# Git push failed,could not resolve host

Tags: git, github

I have a repository on github, and while trying to sync I get an error telling me It has "failed to sync this branch".

In the shell, after running git push i get:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bg1987/ooad4.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

I tried several repos I have and they have the same error.

Changing my DNS servers to googles DNS didn't help.

Comment: Try again now, I just accessed your repo and all seems fine

Comment: stil the same, I dont think its a problem with the repo, probably on my machine.
However there is code I really need to submit =\

Comment: Try to ping github, what does that say?

Comment: This is most definitely a problem with network or firewall. Are you able to access internet at all from this machine?

Comment: Akash was right, my kaspersky was blocking the upload, I feel silly now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears my Kaspersky firewall was blocking the request.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue due to firewall blockage. Then I switched to my personal internet connection and code pushed successfully.

**Check Firewall and Antivirus Software:** Sometimes, firewall or antivirus software may block connections to certain websites. Temporarily disable any firewall or antivirus software and try again.

**Verify DNS Settings:**
Sometimes DNS settings can cause issues. You can try switching to a public DNS service